i18next + gatsby: how to translate only two pages, ignore others
The problem: I'm using Gatsby.js/React in my project. I need to translate only two pages, for example /about and /contacts.
I have two languages in settings: EN and DE. Default language is EN, and when the EN is selected, there's no prefix after domain name, and when DE is selected, there's '/de' afterdo main name.
I need to ignore all pages except /about and /contacts and do not add '/de' after domain name for any page except these two pages. Is it possible? There's no info about such feature in i18next docs.
My gatsby-config:
module.exports = {

...
  plugins: [
...
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next`,
      options: {
        localeJsonSourceName: `locale`,
        languages: [`en`, `de`],
        defaultLanguage: `en`,
        siteUrl: `https://mmmmmm.com`,
        trailingSlash: "always",
        i18nextOptions: {
          interpolation: {
            escapeValue: false,
          },
          keySeparator: false,
          nsSeparator: false,
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};


